# Ignore updates to files in image only after building with Skaffold for the first time?

Tags: skaffold

I have a deployment that includes an Angular project. To test my Angular project, I use `ng serve` which hosts its own fast-updating server I can connect to. For development, I save and edit these files very frequently. Because this image is used in my Skaffold deployment, that means Skaffold is constantly rebuilding and compiling my angular project.

For times that I'm not actively updating the Angular side of things, I'd like it to just build the most recent files and then never check for updates on them again until I run `skaffold dev` again.

Currently the skaffold.yaml looks like this for the Angular image:

```
    - image: angular
      context: ../Images/angular
      custom:
        dependencies:
          ignore: ['../Images/angular']
```

This successfully runs the angular image once and then never checks for updates to it again, but if I make changes to it, stop Skaffold, then run `skaffold dev` again, it doesn't rebuild the image.

I understand *why* it's doing this, it makes sense and is expected. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle the building of images for images that change rapidly while developing them, such as Vue/Angular/React. Or maybe there's a better way to define files as being ignored from changes *during* `skaffold dev` rather than all changes even between runs.

The main reason I'd like to stop the constant building it to save laptop battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skaffold supports other *trigger* modes including a *manual* trigger mode:

```
skaffold dev --trigger=manual
```

Skaffold will then wait for you to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to initiate the next dev rebuild.

An alternative is to use the [Skaffold Control API](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/api/) to toggle the auto-building.  For example, you can use the REST API to turn off the auto-build:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"enabled":false}' localhost:50052/v1/build/auto_execute
```

You can then re-enable it as you desire.  You can use the Control API to toggle auto-deploy instead if you want the images to be built but not deployed (e.g., to see build-time errors), and you can also manually trigger builds/deploys/sync too.

---

You can find out the control port by running `skaffold dev -v info`; the gRPC port is normally 50051 and the REST port is normally 50052:

```
$ skaffold dev -v info
INFO[0000] starting gRPC server on port 50051
INFO[0000] starting gRPC HTTP server on port 50052
INFO[0000] Skaffold &{Version:v1.23.0 ConfigVersion:skaffold/v2beta15 GitVersion: GitCommit:e8f3c652112c338e75e03497bc8ab09b9081142d BuildDate:2021-04-28T00:55:12Z GoVersion:go1.14.14 Compiler:gc Platform:darwin/amd64} 
...
```

Or you can explicitly configure a port:

```
skaffold dev --rpc-http-port=50099
```

For older versions of Skaffold, you may need to explicitly turn on the RPC mode with `--enable-rpc`.